# How do I use a Twitter username as my user id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running a rails 4 app using Omniauth with Twitter. I'm trying to achieve something close to producthunt.com, where they authenticate users and use their Twitter username as their url id.

Comment: Reading [this](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) might be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the url to look like this: example.com/users/username
**instead of** example.com/users/123

If so, all you have to do is change the way you find the de correct user in your Users (or whatever you call your user model) controller. Currently it probably looks like this:

```
#Users Controller
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# Your path to that user is probably this:
user_path(123) #basically you pass the user.id
```

The code above is using **Model.find(#)** to look for the user. The .find() looks the user up by its id#. Instead, you want to find it by the username, not id. To do this use the **Model.find_by** You can see all the ways of querying [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).
Also, whenever you look for the path to find the user show page, istead of sending the id # to the url, you now have to send the username string.

Your new setup should look like this:

```
#Users Controller
def show
 @user = User.find_by :username params[:id] 
#this assumes you have it in your DB as username.  Some twitter apps save it as screen_name. 
end

# Your path to that user is probably this:
user_path('username') #basically you pass the username instead. current_user.username? I dont know what you call in in your app.
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @dataker in that case please mark it as answered. Thanks!